# phpからMySQLの（ルーチンタブ）ストアドプロシージャを呼び出すことができない件に関して。

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

お世話になります。何卒よろしくお願い致します。

以下のサイトを参考にphpからMySQLに設定した(ルーチンタブ内に作成した)ストアドプロシージャを起動させようとしておりますが、エラーが出ないものの、起動もできません。

[MySQLのストアドプロシージャを呼び出す](https://phpjpn.com/?MySQL%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%82%92%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99)

以下はphpの記述と、MySQLの設定です。どこに問題があるかご指摘、ご教示等頂けませんでしょうか。

*php側では、db接続に関する記述（$connect_db、$connect_user、$connect_passwd）を異なるものにするとエラーが出ます。また、$stmt = $dbh->prepareをprepaなどと変更するとエラーになりますが、CALL get_image(:code)自体をCALL get_ima(:code)と変更してもエラーが出ないことを考えると、データベースに接続し、$stmtを実行しようとしているのは確かだけれど、ストアドプロシージャの呼び出し、'CALL get_image(:code)'をしていない、あるいは、ができていないと考えられます。

*MySQLのストアドプロシージャのwhere句のcodeにテーブルtbl_productsに存在するproduct_id、例えば12を設定し、mySql上で”実行する”を押すと期待通りの結果になります。即ち設定したストアドプロシージャの内容、テーブル上でt1.main_image に t1.main_image_xを挿入致します。

データベース：MySQL5.0.77
PHP：5.0.22
WEBサーバ：apache2

**phpの設定**

```
try {
  $connect_db = "mysql:dbname=xxxxxxx;host=localhost";
  $connect_user = 'xxxxxxx';
  $connect_passwd = 'xxxxxxx';

  //データベース接続
  $dbh = new PDO(
        $connect_db,
        $connect_user,
        $connect_passwd,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
  );

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare('CALL get_image(:code)');
  $code = '12';//　最終的にはシステム的に変数を代入する設定にする
  $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
  // ストアドプロシージャをコールします
  $stmt->execute();

 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 echo $row['t1.main_image'];
  }
} catch(PDOException $e){
   var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
}
// 切断
$dbh = null;
```

**MySQL ストアドプロシージャの設定**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxxxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_image(IN code varchar(2))`()
    NO SQL
BEGIN

UPDATE tbl_products t1 SET t1.main_image = t1.main_image_x WHERE t1.product_id = code;

End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: PHPとMySQLのバージョンを共有いただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: phpからではなく、MySQL上で `CALL get_image( 12 )` を実行した場合は期待通りの結果になってますか？

Comment: take88様、Keitaro_so様、
感謝いたします。CALL get_image( 12 )、にするとwhere句のcodeの関連がなくなるため、#1054-Unknown column 'code' in 'where clause'となります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CALL get_image('12'); でエラーになるという時点で、そもそも期待通りにストアドプロシジャが作成できていないということです。

「get_image」がストアドプロシジャ名であり続きの括弧の中「(IN code varchar(2))」は引数の宣言ですよね？であれば以下のようになるのではないでしょうか？

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxxxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_image`(IN code varchar(2))
    NO SQL
BEGIN

UPDATE tbl_products t1 SET t1.main_image = t1.main_image_x WHERE t1.product_id = code;

End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

質問にお書きになられたソースコードでは「get_image(IN code varchar(2))」という名前で、引数がないストアドプロシジャを定義している状態です。

ご確認ください。

Comment: sa-y様、ご教授感謝いたします。IN code varchar(2)内の数字に関して、例えば、桁数が3,4,5桁と増えていくケースはどのように記述すれば宜しいのでしょうか。

Comment: そもそも質問にテーブル構造が記述されていないのですが、 tbl_products テーブルの product_id カラムの型は何型なのでしょうか？ 桁数が増えるということは int (integer) なのでしょうか？ 仮に int だとしたならば、 get_image() の引数 code の型も int であるべきではないでしょうか？ `get_image`(IN code int)

Comment: sa-y様、php側からのproduct_id（手入力）がmySqlに到達し、tbl_productsに既につくられている行に対して期待通りの機能を果しております。長くて恐縮ですがもう一つ質問がございまして、php側からこの情報を受けた際に、mySql側でこのプロシージャの作業を数秒遅らせるようなことは可能でしょうか。(理由はそのphpでの第一の作業はtbｌ_productsに商品を挿入することで、その後、商品挿入によって作成された行に対してこのプロシージャでUPDATEをかけようとしているのですが、プロシージャのタイミングが早すぎるのかphpがtbl_productsに作成しているものと同じproduct_idの変数でcodeを渡した際（テスト的に行った既に作られているproduct_idを手入力ではなく）にプロシージャが機能しません。このような場合、phpでそのような遅延の設定をしなければならないのか、mySqlで可能なのか、あるいは今申し上げたこと事態は不可能なのか、ご意見をお伺いできませんでしょうか。

Comment: a-y様、ご教授頂きまして感謝いたします。ご提示頂きました記述にて期待通りの機能を果しております。また長々と大変失礼いたしました。それでは終了とさせて頂きます。